# I want a completely separate page from my Wordpress-installation

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress-driven project and want to add 1 single page to that project, that has entirely nothing to do with wordpress at all, but just consists of plain html - no links from the one to the other; nothing. This page shall be accessible via abc.com/folder while the original wordpress-project is still all over abc.com

What would be the best way to do this? Just add the folder and page, or do I also need to do something on the htaccess-file?

thanks

Comment: No just add the folder :)

Comment: Just create that folder and name your html `index.html` inside that folder

Comment: nearly thought it'd be easy as that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create that folder and name your html `index.html` inside that folder. This way that html file can be accessed via abc.com/folder